# How to generate iTunes Connect promo codes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I cannot generate promo codes for my iOS app in iTunes Connect. Usually I select the app, and then the app version, and the link to generate is located at the bottom of the page under Additional Information. However it is gone.

[image: Location to generate promo codes in iTunes Connect]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

iTunes Connect has moved the location where the promo codes are generated.

To generate promo codes as of 10/22/2015 select the app -> Features -> Promo codes

[image]

Comment: Every single time I need one of these codes I have to try and remember what it is called - then I need to come and do a search on SO to find out where Apple have hidden it! And the ridiculous iTunes Connect website is so unbelievably slow!!!

Answer (score 1):

App Store Connect has moved the location again. It is now located under the "Services" heading for your app, rather than the old "Features" heading.

[image]